# Is it possible to change the string of EICAR file?

Tags: malware

Is it possible to change the string of EICAR file and still detectable?

For example, print "KGMAL" instead of "EICAR".

Comment: Aren't you basically asking if you can replace a blue car with a red car and still make it detectable as blue? The point of a definition like EICAR is that any detection will just check for exactly the defined string only, not behavior or anything else. I cannot understand the point of this question.

Comment: It would take 30 seconds to change the text and upload it to VirusTotal... You do not specify what changes you want to make or how much of the string you which to modify, or what context.

Comment: Right. It took me 25 seconds to test this... Go to EICAR site, copy string, open text editor, paste string, modify string, save, paste into new file, save without modifications. Your AV will give you your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Eicar.org defines the 68-byte string as the detectable "virus":

```
Any anti-virus product that supports the EICAR test file should
detect it in any file providing that the file starts with the 
following 68 characters, and is exactly 68 bytes long:

X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*

The first 68 characters is the known string.
```

They do allow for limited expansion of the file:

```
It may be optionally appended by any combination of whitespace
characters with the total file length not exceeding 128 characters.
The only whitespace characters allowed are the space character,
tab, LF, CR, CTRL-Z.
```

But it's fair to say that any modification of the initial 68 bytes used in the definition will harm recognition of the file by antivirus vendors.  I suppose it's *possible* that some vendors may match a subset of that 68 bytes, but it's not *likely*.